# adb run-as: package listed but errors as 'unknown'

Tags: android, shell, cordova

I have written an app for a Galaxy Tab, in a Windows 7 environment.  I am wanting to use 'adb shell' to look at files in my app's 'cordova.file.dataDirectory'.  I launch the adb shell without problems.  The snippet below shows that even though the package is listed, 'run-as' errors out with 'package unknown'.

```
shell@matissewifiue:/ $ pm list packages
...
package:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service
package:org.crosswalkproject.xwalkembed
...
shell@matissewifiue:/ $ run-as org.crosswalkproject.xwalkembed
run-as: Package 'org.crosswalkproject.xwalkembed' is unknown
shell@matissewifiue:/ $
```

I get the same error whether or not the shell is running as root.  Why is adb not recognising the package in the 'run-as' command?

Comment: This means that you don't have appropriate permissions. In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, have you set `android:debuggable="true"` in the `application` tag?

Comment: I set the attribute in /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml, but stil get the same error.

Comment: Well you need to set the attribute in your App's `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: This may help: http://visualgdb.com/KB/?ProblemID=nopkg