# Android APK installs manually but not programmatically

Tags: android, cordova

I have written an app that is designed to download an .apk and install it.  while the download seems to execute, the installation errors out with a parse error.

If I download the .apk manually from my repository in to the devices Download directory, I can install it without any problems.

The relevant parts of the code are at an [earlier stack question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808057/cordova-android-how-to-manually-access-persistent-file-location).

How can the same file not install when downloaded programmatically?

[SOLVED] changed download location from

```
var toLocation = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/" + file;
```

to

```
var toLocation = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + file;
```

Comment: Assuming that the path is still largely the same as in that answer, that is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and third-party apps have no rights to access files from other apps' internal storage.

Comment: Tnx.  That insight worked,  I edited above to show the fix.